# Libgdx calculate PerspectiveCamera view in 2d

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I need to calculate the camera view bounds in 2d, `x` `y` `width` and `height`

[image]

In this screen shot the grid is each 1 unit, I need to calculate the bounding box of the 3d view, in the example image above, the results should be:

```
float x = -3;
float y = 0;
float width = 14;
float height = 6;
```

Comment: The view bounds (the frustum) are a truncated pyramid shape, so the 2D bounds vary by distance from the camera. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Im trying to make a tiled map in 3d, Im using TiledMap editor to create the map in  2d, to then replace 2d tile to 3d models. Now I'm trying to make a `TiledMapRenderer3D`,  and to determine which tile I should render I need this, similar to `TiledMapRenderer` `viewBounds`  . It doesnt have to be exact, I can live with rendering a few models out of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your camera is always going to be looking down at your world so the horizon is not visible, and that the camera is always looking parallel to the Y axis of the map so the horizontal lines are never crooked, I think this is a matter of calculating the width of the farthest away line that is within view, because that is where perspective will be showing you the most tiles horizontally. This will get you a rectangular area of the tiled map that fully covers the frustum, although you'll be drawing some extra tiles at the near corners.

```
private final Ray tmpRay = new Ray();
private final Vector3 tmpVec = new Vector3();
private final Rectangle visibleTilesRegion = new Rectangle();

private void updateVisibleTilesRegion (){
    // Define a ray that is a projection of the direction the camera is looking onto the 
    // tile plane (assuming it is a Z=0 plane).
    tmpRay.origin.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, 0f);
    tmpRay.direction.set(0f, 1f, 0f);

    //Find top and bottom
    Intersector.intersectRayPlane(tmpRay, camera.frustum.planes[4], tmpVec);
    float yTop = tmpVec.y;
    Intersector.intersectRayPlane(tmpRay, camera.frustum.planes[5], tmpVec);
    float yBottom = tmpVec.y;

    // Find left and right at the top of the screen by intersecting that line with the left 
    // and right planes
    tmpRay.origin.set(camera.position.x, yTop, 0f);
    tmpRay.direction.set(-1f, 0f, 0f);
    Intersector.intersectRayPlane(tmpRay, camera.frustum.planes[2], tmpVec);
    float xLeft = tmpVec.x;
    tmpRay.direction.set(1f, 0f, 0f);
    Intersector.intersectRayPlane(tmpRay, camera.frustum.planes[3], tmpVec);
    float xRight = tmpVec.x;

    visibleTilesRegion.set(xLeft, yBottom, xRight - xLeft, yTop - yBottom);
}
```